# find the power series expansion of $f(z)$ at $z_0$ without computing derivatives

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Is it possible to find the power series expansion of $f(z)=\log z$ at $z_0=1$ without computing derivatives?

Answer (score 3):

I assume "look it up" doesn't count.

You can do it with  antiderivatives: start with the geometric series
for $1/z = 1/(1 + (z-1))$, and integrate term-by-term.